# Whitespace for no reason

Tags: html, css, whitespace, margin, padding

I'm building a responsive website and I've got a problem. The width of the mobile version of the site needs to be 100%, I managed to do this but something is creating whitespace on the right side (which causes a horizontal scroll).

I have been searching all day for the cause of this but I don't manage to find it.

The problem appears when the window-width is below 600 pixels.

The code of my website:

HTML

```
    <body>
<div class="container">
    <header>
        <div class="top-border"></div>
        <div class="header-content">
            <div class="logo"><img alt="Tuinservice Duckers" src="images/logo.png" width="294" height="64" /></div>
            <div class="menuknop">Menu</div>
            <nav class="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li class="geenmargemenu"><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nieuws</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Over ons</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Foto's</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Tuintips</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </header>

    <div class="fullwidthimg">
    <div class="message">
    <h1 class="displayfull headerheading">Welkom, wij zijn Tuinservice Duckers.</h1>
    <h1 class="displaymobile headerheading">Home</h1>
    <a href="#" class="button"><h2>Bekijk onze tuinen</h2></a></div>
    <img width="1920" height="350" alt="Afbeelding Tuin" src="images/slider/IMG_4708.jpg" />
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="content">
    <h1 class="homedriekolom">Wij zijn een gepassioneerd hoveniersbedrijf gevestigd in Stein.</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="contentcontainer">
    <div class="content">
    <div class="glyph driekolom begindivs">
        <div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xf383;"></div>
        <h2>Ontwerp</h2>
        <p>Samen met u ontwerpen wij een unieke tuin, een project op maat dat volledig aan uw wensen voldoet. Wij zullen niet tevreden zijn totdat u dat ook bent.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="glyph driekolom negenzestigmarge begindivs">
        <div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xf290;"></div>
        <h2>Aanleg</h2>
        <p>Ons professionele team legt op vakkundige wijze uw tuin aan en denkt daarbij aan elk detail. De aanleg wordt volledig verzorgd zodat u uw handen vrij heeft.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="glyph driekolom begindivs">
        <div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xf039;"></div>
        <h2>Onderhoud</h2>
        <p>Ook voor het onderhouden van uw tuin kunt u terecht bij Tuinservice Duckers. Zo bent u er altijd van verzekerd dat uw tuin in de perfecte staat verkeerd.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    </div>



    <div class="content">
    <h1 class="homedriekolom">Onze tuinen</h1>
    <span class="onderschrift">Onze tuinontwerpen kenmerken zich door een mooi lijnenspel, waarbij rust in het ontwerp de boventoon voert. Zelf noemen wij onze ontwerpen 'no-nonsense tuinen', met niet veel poespas maar zoals tuinen behoren te zijn.</span>
    <div class="driekolimg"><img src="images/design/homeimages/IMG_1511.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="driekolimg"><img src="images/design/homeimages/IMG_4666.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="driekolimg negenzestigweg"><img src="images/design/homeimages/IMG_4708.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="contentnotop hidemobile">
    <h1 class="homedriekolom">Partners</h1>
    <span class="onderschrift">Voor het aanleggen van onze tuinen gebruiken wij alleen materiaal van de hoogste kwaliteit, dit wordt mogelijk gemaakt door de volgende bedrijven.</span>
    <div class="vierkolom vierkolimg"><a href="http://www.tuinserviceduckers.nl/"><img src="images/logo-s/BW_Duckers.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/logo-s/Duckers.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logo-s/BW_Duckers.png'" /></a></div>
    <div class="vierkolom vierkolimg"><a href="http://in-lite.nl/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logo-s/BW_Inlite.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/logo-s/Inlite.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logo-s/BW_Inlite.png'" /></a></div>
    <div class="vierkolom vierkolimg"><a href="http://www.tigerturf.nl/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logo-s/BW_TigerTurf.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/logo-s/TigerTurf.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logo-s/BW_TigerTurf.png'" /></a></div>
    <div class="vierkolom vierkolimg"><a href="http://www.gardena.com/nl/" target="_blank"><img src="images/logo-s/BW_Gardena.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/logo-s/Gardena.png'" onmouseout="this.src='images/logo-s/BW_Gardena.png'" /></a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer">

    <div class="footercontainer">

    <div class="footerkolom hidemobile">
    <h2>Over ons</h2>
    <p>Als gepassioneerd hoveniersbedrijf houden wij ons voornamelijk bezig met het aanleggen van tuinen en bestratingen. Ook voor het ontwerp en onderhoud kunt u bij ons terecht.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerkolom">
    <h2>Contact</h2>
    <p>
    <span class="vijfhonderd">Tuinservice Duckers</span><br />
    Maasbanderkerkweg 36<br />
    6171 RT, Stein<br />
    +31 (0) 46 433 81 46<br />
    info@tuinserviceduckers.nl
    </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footerkolom negenzestigweg">
    <h2>Laatste nieuws</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis suscipit accumsan quam, sodales vulputate velit dapibus ac. Nam nibh augue, congue sit amet ornare quis, imperdiet rutrum magna.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
    </footer>
    <div class="footerbottom">
    <div class="footerbottomkolom">
    <div class="rights hidemobile">&copy; Tuinservice Duckers, <a href="http://www.visiamedia.nl" target="_blank" title="Webdesign & Grafisch ontwerp Limburg"><strong>design</strong> door Visia Media</a></div>
    <div class="socialmedia"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/TuinserviceDuckers" target="_blank" title="Volg Tuinservice Duckers op Facebook"><div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe001;"></div></a><a href="http://www.twitter.com/tsDuckers" target="_blank" title="Volg Tuinservice Duckers op Twitter"><div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe000;"></div></a><a href="http://plus.google.com/118078160798794822832/" target="_blank" title="Volg Tuinservice Duckers op Google+"><div class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe002;"></div></a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
    @charset "utf-8";

    * {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight:400;
    color:#676767;
    font-size:15px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:none;
    line-height:145%;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, .fs1 {
    color:#403f3f;
    font-weight:300;
    }

    strong {
    font-weight:500;
    color:inherit;
    font-size:inherit;
    }

    h1.homedriekolom {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    }
h1.homedriekolom strong {
    font-weight:500;
}
.onderschrift {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:17px;
    font-weight:300;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:20px 0px 40px;
    color:#403f3f;
}
span.homequote {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:21px;
    font-style:italic;
    display:inline-block;
    font-weight:300;
}

body, html {
    background-color:white;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

.container {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

header {
    width:100%;
}

.top-border {
    width:100%;
    height:6px;
    background-color:#9cab5c;
}

.header-content {
    width:950px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:0 5px;
}

.logo {
    float:left;
}
.logo img {
    height:32px;
    margin-top:16px;
    width:auto !important;
}

.menu {
    float:right;
    margin:20px 0;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style:none;
}
.menu ul li {
    display:inline;
    margin-left:22px;
}
.menu ul li a {
    color:#565656;
}
.menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li a.active {
    color:#9cab5c;
}

.clear {
    width:100%;
    clear:both;
    margin-top:-1px;
}

.fullwidthimg {
    position:relative;
}
.fullwidthimg, .fullwidthimg img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto !important;
}

.fullwidthimg .message {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    width:950px;
    padding:0 5px;
    margin-left:-480px;
    text-align:center;
    height:136px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-68px;
}
.fullwidthimg .message h1 {
    color:white;
    font-size:43px;
    font-weight:300;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #384523;
}
.fullwidthimg .message .button {
    padding:15px 30px;
    background-color:#9cab5c;
    margin-top:14px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.fullwidthimg .message .button h2 {
    color:white;
    font-size:15px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-weight:400;
}
.fullwidthimg .message .button:hover {
    background-color:#8d9b50;
}

.contentnotop {
    width:950px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:0px 5px 40px;
}
.contentnotop p {
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

.content {
    width:950px;
    margin:0px auto;
    padding:60px 8px;
}
.contentcontainer {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
}

.content p {
    margin-bottom:7px;
}

.begindivs {
    text-align:center;
}
.begindivs .fs1 {
    font-size:40px;
    line-height:40px;
}
.begindivs h2 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:22px;
    font-weight:500;
    margin:20px 0 -5px;
}
.begindivs p {
    width:84%;
    margin:20px auto 0;
    font-size:14px;
}
.driekolom {
    width:33.3%;
    float:left;
}
.driekolimg {
    width:33.3%;
    float:left;
}
.driekolimg img {
    width:93%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}

.vierkolom {
    width:25%;
    height:12,5%;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.vierkolimg img {
    width:70%;
    margin-top:-50%;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
}

footer {
    margin-top:32px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#9cab5c;
    height:300px;
    color:white;
}
.footerbottom {
    background-color:#8d9b50;
    color:white;
}
.footerbottomkolom {
    color:white;
    width:960px;
    margin:auto;
    font-size:17px;
    padding:12px 0 12px;
}
.footerbottomkolom a {
    font-size:17px;
    color:white;
}
footer a {
    color:white;
}
.socialmedia {
    float:right;
    width:auto;
    text-align:right;
}
.socialmedia .fs1 {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:20px;
    margin:5px 0px 0px 13px;
}
.socialmedia * {
    font-size:inherit;
    color:white;
}
.rights {
    font-size:inherit;
    color:white;
    float:left;
}

.push {
    height:300px;
}

.footercontainer {
    width:950px;
    padding:67px 5px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.footerkolom {
    width:28.3%;
    float:left;
    padding-right:5%;
}
.footerkolom h2 {
    color:white;
    font-weight:600;
    font-size:19px;
    line-height:19px;
    margin-bottom:23px;
}
.footerkolom p {
    color:white;
    line-height:22px;
}

.vijfhonderd {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
}

.displaymobile {
    display:none;
}


/* ICONS */

@font-face {
    font-family: 'whhglyphs';
    src:url('fonts/whhglyphs.eot');
    src:url('fonts/whhglyphs.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/whhglyphs.woff') format('woff'),
        url('fonts/whhglyphs.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/whhglyphs.svg#whhglyphs') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

[data-icon]:before {
    font-family: 'whhglyphs';
    content: attr(data-icon);
    speak: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    line-height: 1;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.menuknop {
    display:none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 960px) {

.fullwidthimg .message .button {
    padding:0px;
    background-color:#9cab5c;
    margin:0px;
    display:none;
}
.fullwidthimg, .fullwidthimg img {
    width:100%;
    height:auto !important;
}

.fullwidthimg .message {
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    width:96%;
    padding:0 2%;
    margin-left:-50%;
    text-align:center;
    padding:0;
    height:34px;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-22px;
}
    .fullwidthimg .message h1 {
    color:white;
    font-size:34px;
    line-height:34px;
    font-weight:300;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #384523;
    }

    .header-content {
    width:100%;
    padding:0px 0%;
    }

    h1.homedriekolom {
    line-height:135%;
    }

    .content, .contentnotop {
    width:96%;
    padding: auto 2%;
    }

    .negenzestigweg {
    display:none;
    }

    .driekolimg {
    width:48%;
    margin:1%;
    }

    .driekolimg img {
    width:100% !important;
    }

    .driekolom {
    width:100%;
    }
    .negenzestigmarge {
    margin:60px 0px;
    }
    .driekolom p {
    width:65%;
    }

    .footercontainer {
    width:100%;
    padding:67px 0px !important;
    }

    .footerkolom {
    width:46%;
    padding-left:2% !important;
    padding-right:2% !important;
    float:left;
}

.footerbottom {
    width:100% !important;
}
.footerbottomkolom {
    width:96%;
    padding:auto 2% auto 2% !important;
}

.menu ul li.geenmargemenu {
    margin-left:10px !important;
}

.logo {
    margin-left:2%;
}
.menu {
    margin-right:2%;
}

}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {


    html, body {
        width:100% !important;
        padding:0 !important;
        margin:0 !important;
    }

    .header, .header-content {
        width:100%;
        padding:0 !important;
        margin:0 !important;
    }

    .menuknop {
    display:block !important;
    color:white;
    background-color:#8d9b50;
    width:92% !important;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:18px;
    padding:5px 4% !important;
    margin:0 !important;
} 

    .menu {
        width:100%;
        margin:0 !important;
        display:none;
        padding:0 !important;
    }
    .menu ul li, .menu ul li.geenmargemenu {
        width:100%;
        display:block;
        margin:0 !important;
        padding:0 !important;
        background-color:#9cab5c;
    }
    .menu ul li:hover {
        background-color:#8d9b50;
    }

    .menu ul li a {
        color:white;
        font-size:18px;
        padding:5px 4%;
        width:92%;
        display:block;
    }
    .menu ul li a:hover, .menu ul li a.active {
        color:white;
    }

    .logo {
        float:none;
        margin:auto;
        display:block;
        width:100%;
        padding:0 !important;
        height:auto !important;
    }
    .logo img {
        width:60% !important;
        height:auto !important;
        display:block;
        margin:26px 20% !important;
    }

    .displaymobile {
        display:block;
    }
    .displayfull, .hidemobile {
        display:none;
    }

    .footerkolom {
    width:96%;
    margin-left:2% !important;
    margin-right:2% !important;
    float:left;
    }

    .driekolimg {
    width:96% !important;
    margin:2% !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    }

    .driekolimg img {
    width:100% !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    margin:0 !important;
    }

    .socialmedia {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 !important;
    padding:0 !important;
    }

    }
```

This is the page I'm talking about:

http://www.visiamedia.nl/duckers/

Comment: Where is your code? (-1)

Comment: As I sad in the post, I didn't post the code because I thought it would be easier to just inspect the elements, I'll post the code right away.

Comment: What happens when you fix the problem? Then this question will be useless because we won't be able to see the broken code.

Comment: One of your elements is overflowing 100%. Check for elements with padding + width 100% or a set width with padding. Hide your major elements one by one until it goes away and you'll know. It's a common problem when building responsive layouts.

Comment: I also thought of that, but I can't find any element which width is 100% and also has a padding. The problem doesn't occur when I hide the footer but I don't see any reason why it's extra wide.

Comment: I fixed the problem on my desktop (the column in the footer had some padding on a different window-size, I should have noticed), but it still happens on my iPhone 5 (a bit less, but the horizontal scroll remains).

Comment: Just to be clear, it doesn't have to be set to 100%, I just meant if the offending element is more than 100% due to some extra padding or what have you. But it seems like your on your way. hiding the main elements one by one until the problem goes away is the first thing i do when I get this happening and it usually lets me find the elm. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help! I managed to find the problem by hiding the elements one by one. The problem was the .content class, it was set to be 94% width and 5px margin, I adjusted it and it all works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the padding on the `content` div at line 174:

```
.content {
    padding: 60px 8px;
}
```

Set that 8px to zero.

Comment: I didn't even notice your answer (I'm sorry but I'm new to this website). You were right, thanks alot anyway!